# fail2ban action ipset retry or timeout

Tags: iptables, fail2ban, ipset

Recently in an Ubuntu 20.04 box from `fail2ban` I got the following error:

```
2023-07-13 06:57:05,129 fail2ban.actions        [3063]: NOTICE  [nginx-http-auth] Ban 2600:1005:b02d:3b6a:c1e:4a7e:6a9f:ccc4
2023-07-13 06:57:05,151 fail2ban.utils          [3063]: ERROR   7f106882c6c0 -- exec: ipset create f2b-nginx-http-auth-v6 hash:ip timeout 600 family inet6
ip6tables -w -I ban -m set --match-set f2b-nginx-http-auth-v6 src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable
2023-07-13 06:57:05,152 fail2ban.utils          [3063]: ERROR   7f106882c6c0 -- timed out after 0 seconds.
2023-07-13 06:57:05,353 fail2ban.utils          [3063]: ERROR   ipset create f2b-nginx-http-auth-v6 hash:ip timeout 600 family inet6
ip6tables -w -I ban -m set --match-set f2b-nginx-http-auth-v6 src -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-port-unreachable -- failed with [Errno 3] No such process
2023-07-13 06:57:05,353 fail2ban.utils          [3063]: ERROR   7f106882c6c0 -- killed with SIGTERM (return code: -15)
2023-07-13 06:57:05,354 fail2ban.actions        [3063]: ERROR   Failed to execute ban jail 'nginx-http-auth' action 'iptables-ipset-proto6-allports' info 'ActionInfo({'ip': '2600:1005:b02d:3b6a:c1e:4a7e:6a9f:ccc4', 'family': 'inet6', 'fid': <function Actions.ActionInfo.<lambda> at 0x7f1068839750>, 'raw-ticket': <function Actions.ActionInfo.<lambda> at 0x7f1068839e10>})': Error starting action Jail('nginx-http-auth')/iptables-ipset-proto6-allports: 'Script error'
```

actionstart from **/etc/fail2ban/action.d/iptables-ipset-proto6-allports.local**

```
actionstart = ipset create <ipmset> hash:ip timeout <default-timeout> <familyopt>
              <iptables> -I <chain> -m set --match-set <ipmset> src -j <blocktype>
```

My understanding about the issue is that `fail2ban` is failing to execute `ipset` / `ip6tables` (deadlock?)

Is there is a way to relax `fail2ban` settings so it retries multiple times or allows a longer timeout before exiting.

Answer (score 1):

In the error logs you shared, it seems that `fail2ban` is encountering issues executing the ipset create and `ip6tables` commands.

To address this problem, you can try adjusting the fail2ban settings to allow for longer retries and timeouts. Here's a possible solution:

Open the `fail2ban` configuration file for editing.

In Ubuntu 20.04, the file is typically located at `/etc/fail2ban/fail2ban.conf`.

Look for the actionban line related to the nginx-http-auth jail. It might look something like this:

```
actionban = ipset create <ipmset> hash:ip timeout <default-timeout> <familyopt>
iptables -I <chain> -m set --match-set <ipmset> src -j <blocktype>
```

Modify the actionban line to include a longer timeout or retry interval.

You can add the `--retry <num>` option to specify the number of retries and the `--timeout <secs>` option to set a longer timeout.

For example:

```
actionban = ipset create <ipmset> hash:ip --timeout 1200 <familyopt>
iptables -I <chain> -m set --match-set <ipmset> src -j <blocktype> --retry 3
```

In the above example, the timeout is set to 1200 seconds (20 minutes), and the retry count is set to 3.

Save the changes to the configuration file and restart the fail2ban service for the modifications to take effect. You can use the following command:

```
sudo service fail2ban restart
```

By adjusting the timeout and retry values in the fail2ban configuration, you are giving it more time to execute the required commands and allowing for additional retries in case of a deadlock situation. This can potentially resolve the issue you're facing.

Remember to monitor the `fail2ban` logs after making the changes to ensure that the issue is resolved and that `fail2ban` functions as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> `timed out after 0 seconds.`

There was an [issue #2790](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2790) with ipset actions, that was caused by name confusion with a `timeout` parameter of action.
Ubuntu 20.04 seems to have outdated fail2ban version.
Try to update [action.d config from 0.11](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/tree/0.11/config/action.d) branch or better upgrade fail2ban from https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/releases (there is a Debian-based package which should work for your Ubuntu, at least 0.11.2 version). Also note [fail2ban :: wiki :: How to install or upgrade fail2ban manually](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/wiki/How-to-install-or-upgrade-fail2ban-manually).